# How to match variables starting with $ with regex?

Tags: regex, match

The case is the following:

I have this string variations:

```
['var1' => $var1, 'var2' => $obj->var1['asd']]
[ 'var1' => $var1, 'var2' => $obj->var1 ]
['var1' => $var1, 'var2' => $var2]
```

I need to match `$var`, `$obj->var1['asd']` and `$obj->var1`.

I came that far:

```
(\$[^,\s\]]+]?)
```

It almost works, but still the last case doesn't. See it in action here: [regex101.com/r/cI0yP0/3](https://regex101.com/r/cI0yP0/3)

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for all your answers. They all work perfectly fine.

Now as Joe pointed out, there might be other cases such as the following.

```
['var' => $obj->var1->var2[2]->var3['test']->var4]
['var1' => $obj->var1[$obj2->var1['one']]]
['var2' => $obj[3]['var']]
['var3' => $obj->method()]
```

Comment: Perhaps, [`(\$[^][,\s]+(?:\[[^][]*])*)`](https://regex101.com/r/zI5vN9/2)?

Comment: @Aley: Your demo shows `$obj->var1` is matched

Comment: @anubhava `$var2]` is the problem. Look the last char.

Comment: ok got it, what regex flavor are you using?

Comment: I use PHP here, so it's PCRE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will allow you to capture any number of variables chained together and won't include the trailing square bracket:

```
 \$(?:(?:(?<!\$)->)?(?:[a-zA-Z]\w*(?:\[[^\[\]]+\])*)(?:\(\))?)+
```

This will capture `$obj->var1->var2[2]->method1()->var3['test']['test2']->method2()` for example.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nA6nP2/4)

*This does not support nested brackets. i.e. `$obj->var1[$obj2->var1['one']]` To balance brackets you would need to use a proper parser*

Comment: Thanks Joe, I forgot about the other cases, but realize now that they might also occurre. Nested brackets and stuff like `$obj[3]['var']` and `$obj->method();` would be very nice to catch.

Comment: I updated to support multiple brackets and method calls. You should really consider a parser depending on what you are trying to do because this can still pickup invalid syntax like `$x[t'es't]y`.

Comment: Thanks Joe! We have a gettext wrapper which takes parameters such as the examples you found in the question. Now they have to be extracted. I'm not sure if there is a parser out there that is doing exactly this.

Answer (score 3):

You brought a nice regex exercise. Below you can find 3 different regex to solve your problem.

### Alternation with multiple groups

Not sure if you may like using a regex like this:

```
(\$.*?),|(\$.*?\])\]|(\$.*?)\]
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/cI0yP0/11)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

### Single group with alternation

However, have improved above regex and can come up with this:

```
(\$.*?\]?)(?:,|\])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/cI0yP0/12)**

---

### Single group with character class

And adding a character class for better performance. I think this is the best.

```
(\$.*?\]?)[,\]]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/cI0yP0/13)**

Comment: Thanks Federico, your explanation is very detailed. I like it a lot!

Comment: Hi @Aley glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

```
(\$[\w]+(?:->[\w]+)?(?:\[.*?\])?)
```

---

**DEMO**

https://regex101.com/r/cI0yP0/6

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex with an optional match in the end for `[...]` part:

```
\$[^][,\s]+(?:\[[^]]*\])?
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cI0yP0/10)

Answer (score 0):

Try following regex:

```
\$.+?(?=,|\s|\])(?:\](?=\]))?
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aL4mF2/2)

Based on your sample input, it will capture:

```
$var1
$obj->var1['asd']
$var1
$obj->var1
$var1
$var2
```